# How to make a command with grep captured fields?

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to capture a process that runs and make an strace of it in one line:

I managed to capture only the one that i want with this command

`ps -ef | grep "[0-9].*[0-9] /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/readcard.py"`

outputs this:

```
root       676   668 99 11:00 ?        00:34:21 /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/readcard.py
```

Now I'm trying to capture the process pid with this regex and use it to make another command:

`ps -ef | grep "([0-9]+).*[0-9] /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/readcard.py"`

How I could make to run something like this?

```
sudo strace -f -p{captured_field} -s9999 -e write
```

Comment: But.. `pgrep -f "/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/readcard.py"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk` for only showing the second column:

```
ps -ef | grep "([0-9]+).*[0-9] /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/readcard.py" | awk '{print $2}'
```

This, you can use it as an input for another command, by embedding it into `$(...)`, as follows:

```
sudo strace -f -p{$(ps -ef | grep "([0-9]+).*[0-9] /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/readcard.py" | awk '{print $2}')} -s9999 -e write
```

Good luck